# Meaning of a pale icon for a framework in XCode

Tags: xcode, frameworks

Sometimes third party frameworks are listed in my project file with pale (semi-transparent?) icons (like PersonalizedAdConsent in the attached screenshot). These frameworks are present as seem to work right.

What is the meaning of that?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the icon is pale iff you add add a local library which is currently inside you workspace. In that situation that pale icon represents only a link to the framework (the .framework file itself is not imported to your app). That's only a theory tho